# 20% visitor drop when changed to HTTPS

Tags: http, https, visitors

quick question if anyone has dealt with this. I moved from HTTP to HTTPS for security reasons, but since moving to HTTPS my visitor count (sessions,views) dropped 20%. It's been almost a month now and the visitor count hasn't gotten up. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Interesting question ... are you requiring visitors to have a modern up to date browser ? with TLS v1.2 which is advised yet will deny visitors not using a current browser ... can you log browser TLS v1.2 readiness during port 80 handshaking prior to requiring 443

Comment: We saw something similar recently with updating OpenSSL in our reverse proxies.  OpenSSL deprecated RC4 and 3-DES.  This stopped anyone on XP from being able to connect.  Does your https server use OpenSSL?  What server is it?